# ¿Por qué AJAX me devuelve un valor diferente?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando mostrar botones (agregar, editar y eliminar) en lugar de los TAGS en un TreeView:

[image: Treeview]

Todo bien hasta ahí pero, al hacer click en el botón de eliminar me devuelve un código totalmente diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que me ayude por favor, o ¿hay otro modo de hacerlo?.

Aquí mi codigo JS(AJAX):

```
function getModalEliminarContabilidad(codigo) {
$.ajax({
    url: url_contabilidad,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        opcion: 'modalEliminar',
        codigo: codigo
    },
})
.done(function(data) {
    $('#srv_contabilidad_modal_eliminar_contenido').html(data);
})
.fail(function() {
})
.always(function() {
});
```

}

Aquí mi código PHP:

```
case 'modalEliminar':
            if (isset($_POST['codigo'])) {
                $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
                ?>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Cuenta Contable: <strong><?= $codigo ?></strong></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4 class="title">¿Seguro que quieres eliminar esta Cuenta Contable?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div id="srv_contabilidad_eliminar_alert"></div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Si</button>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            break;
```

Esto genera el Treeview:

```
case 'treeview':
            $cuenta = $_POST['cuenta'];
            $cta = $_POST['cta'];
            $m = $_POST['m'];

            if ($m == 1) $treeview = $contabilidad->searchContabilidadTreeView($cuenta, $cta);
            elseif ($m == 0 && empty($cuenta)) $treeview = $contabilidad->getContabilidadTreeView();

            $data = array();
            foreach($treeview as $row) {
                $codigo     = $row['codigo'];
                $cta        = $row['cta'];
                $sub_cta    = $row['sub_cta'];
                $div        = $row['div'];
                $sub_div    = $row['sub_div'];
                $analitica1 = $row['analitica1'];
                $analiticam = $row['analiticam'];
                $analitica2 = $row['analitica2'];
                $nivel      = $row['nivel'];
                $fin        = $row['fin'];
                $descripcion = utf8_encode($row['descripcion']);

                if ($nivel == 2) $descripcion = $cta . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 3) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 4) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 5) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 6) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . $analitica1 . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 7) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . $analitica1 . $analiticam . ' - ' . $descripcion;
                elseif ($nivel == 8) $descripcion = $cta . $sub_cta . $div . $sub_div . $analitica1 . $analiticam . $analitica2 . ' - ' . $descripcion;

                $tmp = array();
                $tmp['id']         = $row['codigo'];
                $tmp['text']       = $descripcion;
                $tmp['parent_id']  = $row['ref_id_pcge'];
                $tmp['nivel']      = $nivel;
                $tmp['cta']        = $cta;
                $tmp['tags']       = [
                    '<span title="Eliminar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#srv_contabilidad_modal_eliminar" onclick="getModalEliminarContabilidad('. $codigo .');"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span>',
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#srv_contabilidad_modal_guardar" onclick="getModalSave();"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'
                    ];
                array_push($data, $tmp);
            }

            foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
                $output[$value['id']] = &$value;
            }
            foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
                if($value['parent_id'] && isset($output[$value['parent_id']]))
                    $output[$value['parent_id']]['nodes'][] = &$value;
            }
            foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
                if($value['parent_id'] && isset($output[$value['parent_id']]))
                    unset($data[$key]);
            }

            echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            break;
```

Comment: Sí es correcto. tal y como muestra en el inspector del navegador.

Comment: El codigo del switch es muy largo? Hay, quizas, alguna opcion default que este cambiando el valor del codigo? Creo que es mejor que pongas el codigo del php en ves del treeview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le estas pasando un numero a getModalEliminarContabilidad que inicia con cero 0100000000 eso se convertirá a 16777216 ya que javascript supone que el numero que le pasaste a la función esta en octal y lo convierte a decimal

```
getModalEliminarContabilidad(0100000000)
```

Mandalo como string

```
getModalEliminarContabilidad("0100000000")
```

```js
miFuncion(0100000000);
function miFuncion(codigo)
{
console.log(codigo);
}
```